# Shortcut for search bar in Dictionary.app

Tags: macos, keyboard, dictionary

I was hoping that there was some shortcut for the search bar in Dictionary.app. I tried **⌘+L** as one can do in Safari, hoping it would work, to no avail. Does anyone know a shortcut for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior for the Dictionary.app is that when it first opens the Search Field of the app's Toolbar has focus and one can just start typing.

If one then sets focus to a different part of the GUI, then obviously, focus is removed from the Search Field of the Toolbar, however if while the GUI has focus and one starts typing, then focus is automatically set back to an empty Search Field for the typing of a new query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a shortcut. You can just start typing and it'll automatically replace whatever's in the search box with what you've just typed.